# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void .setDefaultBufferSize on a null object reference

Tags: android, java, nullpointerexception

https://github.com/yabushi/TimeStampCamera

をRUNしようとすると、

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(int, int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.shigeki.timestampcamera.MainActivity.createCameraPreviewSession(MainActivity.java:166)
        at com.example.shigeki.timestampcamera.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:32)
        at com.example.shigeki.timestampcamera.MainActivity$1.onOpened(MainActivity.java:88)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$1.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:118)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:810)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
```

とのエラーメッセージが表示されます。
MainActivityの32,88,118にて
Nullであるオブジェクトを参照してしまっているというエラーだと思うのですが、
解決方法がわかりません。

Answer (score 1):

NPEを回避するために、少なくともNullチェックを追加しておいた方がいいと思います。
[`TextureView.html#isAvailable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html#isAvailable())というメソッドがあるので、これを`mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();`の前に追加した方がいいでしょう。

```
if (!mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
    return; // TODO 正しい例外処理を実装すること
}
```

Comment: isAvailableはgetSurfaceTextureが有効な値となるときtrueを返し、if文が

Comment: 途中で途切れてしまいましたので追記させていただきます。…if文が実行されると思うのですが、有効な場合に実行される領域で例外処理を行うということで良いのしょうか。

Comment: おっと、失礼しました。if分の条件が逆でした...訂正しました

Comment: `getSurfaceTexture()`がnullを返す場合は、`isAvailable()`は`false`を返します。詳しくは[実装](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/f76a50c/core/java/android/view/TextureView.java)を見てください。